# How can I solve 'Could not load file or assembly' error in XAML Designer for C# WPF app using C++ managed dll wrapper?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, dll

I have a .NET Framework 4 C# WPF application that uses functions from a referenced managed dll wrapper (a wrapper that wraps an unmanaged C++ dll).
So:

`HMI_Main <— HMI_ClientWrap <— HMI_Client <— HMI_IPC`

Where:

`HMI_Main: C# executable,`

`HMI_ClientWrapper: C++ managed dll`

`HMI_Client : C++ unmanaged dll`

`HMI_IPC: C++ unmanaged dll`

This all works fine in Release configuration and my XAML designer displays my usercontrols.
In Debug configuration, however, no usercontrols are displayed in XAML Designer, only the error `Could not load file or assembly ‘HMI_ClientWrapd.dll’ or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.`
The code behind still works fine and can access exported functions from the DLL.

I suppose the problem is within my usercode, but it is very difficult to find the problem as the only thing complaining is the Designer.
depends.exe also shows no problems, and other parts of Visual Studio does not complain, dlls are resolved etc.

Is there any way to troubleshoot the designer?

I've tried finding log files for Visual Studio but it doesn't really seem to exist anything.
Dependency walker doesn't report any problem.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the dlls were located in a different directory and dependency walker was too outdated to display it correctly.

I instead used the forked dependency walker from here: https://github.com/lhak/Dependencies which immediately identified the issue.

The reason release was working was because I had the folder where the dlls were built to in my Windows Path environment variable

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people